# How can I change stencil buffer value at specific pixel in OpenGL (glDrawPixel)

Tags: c++, opengl

I developed a program to read stencil buffer values.

```
for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
    {
        int stencilValue;
        glReadPixels(j,i,1,1, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &stencilValue);
    }
}
```

Let's say I have only 3x3 pixels, and the result of the stencil test is

```
1 1 1
1 1 1 
0 0 0
```

and saved stencil buffer data to

```
vector<Vector3i> S;
```

Now I want to change the stencil buffer value at pixel (2,1) to 1

The expected result is

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
0 1 0
```

How can I do this?
I tried to use

```
int Image[3][3];
for(unsigned int i=0; i<height; i++)
    for(unsigned int j=0; j<width; j++)
          Image[j][i] = S[j](i);
Image[2][1] = 1;
glDrawPixels(3, 3, GL_STENCIL_BITS, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, Image);
```

But the result is not same to my expectation.
There are strange values like 204. when I increased the window size.
What's the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the type be `GL_INT` since you used signed integer data? Additionally `GL_STENCIL_BITS` is not one of the [allowed enumerations](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml) for `glDrawPixels`. You most probably meant `GL_STENCIL_INDEX`. You should really check for `glGetError()`.

Comment: Oh. That's my mistake. I solved my problem.

Comment: You should explain how you solved your problem as an answer, other people might have similar issues.